# type object 'datetime.time' has no attribute 'time'

Tags: python, datetime, time

```
from datetime import date
from datetime import time

start_time=time.time()
print(start_time)
```

Error message : `type object 'datetime.time' has no attribute 'time'`

But it work if i replace `from datetime import time` to `import time`

why these works like these

Comment: Because the [`datetime.time` class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#time-objects) and the [`time` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html) are two different things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write

```py
from datetime import time
```

there is a module named `datetime` (a Python file `datetime.py`) with a class named time in it:
[image]

while the line:

```py
import time
```

means to import a *different* module named `time` (`time.py`).